# Javascript date format inside NestJs

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, nestjs

I have a `ScrapeResult` mikroOrm entity, I am trying to create a new Date by using this piece of code `newScrapeResult.date = new Date()` and I am getting 2022-07-17T17:07:24.494Z this output.

I need to convert the above format to  `yyyy-mm-dd hh mm ss` this format. How can I do this? I will save this format to database.

Comment: Look for [moment](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: moment is deprecated. Don't use it. Alternatives: [dayjs](https://day.js.org/), [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/)

Comment: btw there's nothing nestjs-specific thing for date manipulation. Search on date manipulation on **nodejs** instead. Nest doesn't replaces Node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you

```js
function currentTime() {
    let date = new Date()
    let a = date.getFullYear()
    let b = date.getMonth()+1 // JS months are 0 indexed, 0 = January, 11 = December
    let c = date.getDate()

    let d = date.getHours()
    let e = date.getMinutes()
    let f = date.getSeconds()

    return a+'-'+b+'-'+c+' '+d+' '+e+' '+f
}
console.log(currentTime())
```

Comment: You could also template literal instead of string concatenation. `\`${data.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()+1}-${date.getDate()} ${date.getHours()} ${date.getMinutes()} ${date.getSeconds()}\``

Comment: When I try to assign  `a+'-'+b+'-'+c+' '+d+' '+e+' '+f` to   `newScrapeResult.date`  this format, I am getting this error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.`

Comment: Don't tell the function to return a `Date`, tell it to return a `string`. Or you might need to update the DTO/make a new one so this field can be a `string` instead of a `Date`